# Google Maps search shows second business at same address

Tags: google-maps

I have a friend with two businesses at the same physical address.

http://alliancebjjmn.com/
and
http://crossfitmn.com/

He used to use the same website for both businesses, but now they are separate. The issue that arose is when you search for `Crossfit` in the Minneapolis area, his jiu-jitsu school shows up the in search results, instead of the, as seen here (item B): http://g.co/maps/8g3au.

This seems to be an issue with how Google returns results for searches.

How can he make sure the CrossFit studio shows up when `crossfit` is searched, and the jiu-jitsu school shows up for `jiu-jitsu`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Select the arrow next to the place in the listings on the right.
2. Choose "Report a problem"
3. Select "Listing contains incorrect information or spam."
4. Select "Category" from the dropdown and enter relevant information about the miscategorization

The last time I reported a location error it took about a month but it was resolved.

Comment: I did this, so we'll see what happens. I'll wait a couple days and see if anyone else replies, then I'll mark your answer correct.